# Missing case definition in Miranda

Tags: functional-programming, miranda

I'm getting a missing case definition when I'm calling this

```
check c (n:nx) state (l:ls,r:rs)
=true,if((isprefix state c)&(r=n))
=false, otherwise
```

I've checked this and it works on its own no matter what I send it.

This is where I'm calling it from (warning: it's a bit badly written for now):

```
readword input state tape
=output tape, if (((haltcheck sWord sNum state tape)=true)&(isprefix " halt" rline))
=doinst rline state tape , if ((check sWord sNum state tape)=true)
=readword tail state tape, otherwise
  where
  theline = dropwhile notit input
  start = dropwhile  isspace theline
  sWord = takewhile letter start
  ends = dropwhile notspace start 
  distart = dropwhile isspace ends
  sNum = takewhile notspace distart
  tail = dropwhile notspace distart
  rline = takewhile notit tail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing case definition means that you're pattern matching and you don't cover all cases. This happens twice in the definition of your `check` function: You're matching the second parameter with the pattern `n:nx`, but not against the pattern `[]` (so you're not covering the case that the second argument may be the empty list). Similarly you're matching the fourth argument against `(l:ls, r:rs)`, not accounting for the possibility that either of the pair's elements may be the empty list.

So what's happening to cause the error is that when you're calling `check` from `readword` either `sNum` is empty or one of the lists in `tape` is empty.

Comment: thank you very much, didnt think that was it am kicking myself now.